# Why we count a string as a single token in lexical analysis of compiler design?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis, compiler-development

I am learning about compiler design. The task of lexical analyser in compiler is to convert the code into stream of tokes. But I am confused why we consider a string as a single token . For example - `printf("%d is integer", x);` In this statement `printf`, `(`, `"%d is integer"`, `,`, `x`, `)`, `;` are the tokens but why `%d` in string is not considered a separate token?

Comment: Because `%d` has no meaning to the compiler itself. It is being interpreted by the `printf` function and not the compiler. The compiler has no use to different parts of the string, so it should take it as a whole.

Comment: Check the generated assembly: https://godbolt.org/z/Pns6hss7v You'll see that `%d` is not separate from the string literal there either because it doesn't need to be. To the compiler, `%d` means nothing. `printf` is the thing that sees it as a format specifier.

Comment: Note that some modern compilers do understand enough about format strings for `printf()` and `scanf()` and their relatives to be able to diagnose some misuses, but the basic language does not require that.

Comment: Worth mention, I think: a typical C tokenizer reading `printf("%" "d" " " "is" " integer"` would return one `printf` token, one `(` token, and then five separate string tokens. It's up to the next phase of compilation to notice the adjacent string tokens and combine them into a single string. If the compiler does have some sort of printf-format-scanner, it must operate on the resulting combined string, not the individual tokens.

Answer (score 2):

Because format specifiers like `%d` (or any other string contents) are not *syntactically* meaningful - there's no element of the language grammar that depends on them.  String contents (including format specifiers like `%d`) are *data*, not code, and thus not meaningful to the compiler.  The character sequence `%d` is only meaningful at runtime, and only to the `*printf`/`*scanf` families of functions, and only as part of a format string.

To recognize `%d` as a distinct token, you would have to tokenize *the entire string* - `"`, `%d`, `is`, `integer`, `"`.  That opens up a whole can of worms on its own, making parsing of strings more difficult.

Some compilers do examine the format string arguments to `printf` and `scanf` calls to do some basic sanity checking, but that's well after tokenization has already taken place. At the tokenization stage, you don't know that this is a call to the `printf` library function.  It's not until after syntax analysis that the compiler knows that this is a specific library call and can perform that kind of check.